# HTTP Client on Dart not receiving entire body

Tags: json, flutter, rest, dart

I'm writing code to capture a JSON on a website using a REST API. There are no errors but as i testing the parsing, I realized it wasn't capturing the entire length of the body.

Here's an example of the JSON data on the website:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "link": "www.foo.com",
    "bar": "boo",
    "bee": 103,
    "zop": "zap"
}
```

And en example of the code I use to capture the JSON from a URL:

```
var url = Uri.https('XXX.com', 'X/X/X/X/events');
var response = await http.get(url);
Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

Using that code, the variable `jsonData` only holds data until `"bee": 103` and nothing else after that.

I've printed the whole `response.body` and I think thats a problem because I cant see anything past "bee" (as an example). And I'm also certain that the JSON is correct since I can access it from my browser and it's complete. Everything I've seen online related to this question covers problems with the link.

I have a whole list of JSONs i need to parse and `response.body` isn't able to even get through half of one of the elements of that list.

I'd appreciate some help with this :).

Comment: Can you try using postman and share what returns from the get request? How are you certain that it’s an issue with the Dart code and not the server code?

Comment: the json you provided in your question has a comma at the end of "zap"! and that's not a valid form of json. isn't that the problem?

Comment: @OrKeren Okay, I used postman and it's working as expected. i think its an issue either in my code or the way it collects the information because the JSON is used daily for other applications and it works perfectly.

Comment: @MahdiDahouei Apologies for the oversight, the JSON in the question is just a placeholder and not the actual JSON because of NDA reasons. I'll update the question. Thanks.

Comment: you can try using `dio` package to send http requests. it's a better package than `http`

Comment: Still no success...